# Virtuoso Bulk Load Error : error 37000 SP029: TURTLE RDF loader

Tags: rdf, bulk, virtuoso, n-triples

I have loaded a lot of triples as much as 0.9 billion.
However, I have found out that there is some error message as below

error message:
23:47:14 PL LOG:  File /a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/1154148/1154148.nt error 37000 SP029: TURTLE RDF loader, line 14: syntax error processed pending to here

I check out if the triple located line 14(specified in above error message), and the triple was in the Virtuoso when I retrieved it.

what does the message mean? How can I take care of it?

Comment: What's the triple?  Was there actually a syntax error?  How do you know that the same triple wasn't also present somewhere else that *did* get processed?  Did stuff *after* that line get inserted?  There's not really enough information here yet to provide useful help.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. After checking it out, I found out that there was syntax error which I couldn't notice. It was something like double quotation(") escape in String.

Comment: You should either post an answer and accept it (and probably add the extra information to the question), or remove the question altogether, since it doesn't sound like it will be particularly useful to others.  Glad to hear you found a solution, though!  Finding syntax errors in large files can be a real nightmare.

Comment: When dealing with Virtuoso then I always put three quotes on each side of literals, because then they can contain quotes as part of the string. e.g. """This string "contains" quotes"""